# How do you handle database normalization design for optional columns?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, normalization

I am working on a system that stores sensor data. Most sensors measure a single value but some can measure many values for each sample period. I am trying to keep my database as normalized as possible without suffering performance problems for looking up lots of sample data. My question is how to design the sensor data table to account for optional measured data values. For example, sensor A only reads one value, but sensor B reads 5 values. How do I store both sets of data in the data table?

Option 1 is to create a flat structure with a table that has a bunch of columns (value1, value2, value3...valueN, etc) and a field that records how many columns are used. Functional but bad design in my opinion:

```
Sensor Data
  Sensor ID (Pk)
  Timestamp (PK)
  Columns Used
  Value 1
  Value 2
  Value 3
  ...
  Value n
```

The other option is to highly normalize the structure and have a data table that uses a composite key to store individual data values. It would track the sensor id, timestamp, and data type to maintain unique values. This is highly normalized and allows for an unlimited number of optional data values per sample, but duplicates a lot of information (specifically, sensor id and timestamp):

```
Sensor Data
  Sensor ID (Pk)
  Timestamp (Pk)
  Data Type (Pk)
  Value
```

This wouldn't be that bad for a few thousand samples, but this system is designed to store millions of sensor samples and joining those values could suffer performance problems (i.e. WHERE Sensor ID and Timestamp are equal but the Data Type is different).

Anyone have a better idea for designing a database to store optional values? Side note: the design has to work with SQL Server and Entity Framework (EF).

Comment: why not a table (and class) per type of sensor?

Comment: I did consider having a data table for each type of sensor. After all, there is a finite number of sensor types. It just makes it hard to support new sensor types because the database and code would have to be updated for each added sensor type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think going with option 2 is not bad, even if database will have milions of rows. You will only need a index on SensiorId and Timestamp.

I can think of one different design containing two tables:

```
**SensorRead**
Id (PK)
SensorId
Timestamp

**SensorData**
Id(PK)
ReadId(FK)
Value
DataType
```

If you will query that schema for values for given SensorId and timestamp, then it will result in the join between 10 rows (assuming the sensor read's 10 data points). So the cost is almost none.

Aside from the question itself- Im not sure, that having multiple columns as PK's will work good with entity framework... Never tried it, but if you decide to go that way do some research about this.

Comment: That does normalize out some of the duplicated data, but is almost overkill for the sensors that only have a single measured value. This is definitely worth considering, though.

Comment: The only thing that is not "normalized" are the Id's- but those are database ids and do not count- so the data itself is fully normalized.

Comment: Agreed. I currently have a working version that uses composite keys in Entity Framework. It is perfectly happy to use them with the simple schema and small data sets I am working with now.

Comment: Good to know that :) As for the solution- i see, that writing queries in ef will be a liitle more difficult than with your solutions, and could lead to some traps (lazy loading), if the developers will not know what happens behind the scenes. But in terms of performance/normalization I can't think of any other way to solve the issue.

Comment: I find that it is always best to fully normalize all transactional database tables. At some point, you will be glad that you didn't lock the design into a 1 to 1 design. Business groups like to say  "there will never be more than one", and of course, they ask for a 2nd sooner or later.

Comment: @RobertJ.Good Haha, so true.